# Converting date string in unknown format to datetime c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I don't know format of the DateTime because web page has more than one language and more than one Datetime format are available. I had to change poland dateformat in datepicker UI to d.m.yyyy although ISO standard is YYYY-mm-dd. .NET uses ISO standard but whenever I try to use `Convert.ToDateTime(stringDate)` I get exception `String is not recognized as valid DateTime` . I tried using  `Convert.ToDateTime(stringDate,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but it does not help. How to successfully convert to DateTime?

Example:
`item.arrival` is string which can be in more than 10 formats. `Convert.ToDateTime` works for them all.
BUT:
`item.arrival` dateformat for poland language is not anymore `yyyy-mm-dd` (because I had requirement to change it) so `Convert.ToDateTime` not works anymore only for poland language. New format is `13.06.2015.` Because of that, because format is not ISO standard for poland language .NET fails to do conversion. I hope it is more clear now.
 `ArrivalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.arrival,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),`

Comment: What is the value of `stringDate` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? And what do you want as a result?

Comment: If you don't know the format, you can't possibly always get the right results. Is "04/05/2015" May 4th or April 5th? It's not clear where you're trying to get the value from, but if you're in control of the web page you should ideally provide a date picker and then transmit the result in ISO-8601... then use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the ISO format.

Comment: value of string is for example 13.06.2015 and for result I want to be converted to dateTime without exceptions :). Please keep in mind web site uses more than 10 languages and dateFormats so ParseExact I think can't be option.

Comment: Why downvoting? Please explain why and read the question before some random downvoting

Comment: What about the calendar? Thailand, for instance, uses the Buddhist calendar, which is about 543 years ahead of the Gregorian calendar which you're thinking of. Today is 10/3/2558 in Thailand! - edit - the downvoting is because there **is** no answer to your question. It'd be like if I asked you what size trousers to buy me without knowing anything about me.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I understand. I tryed to avoid some "if (customPolandDate)" statements whenever I had to do converting to dateTime because it is error prone and some developers could forget to do it when the trying to convert string to DateTime.

Comment: That doesn't explain how you want to cope with the ambiguous situation. Basically your question is very unclear at the moment - which may well be why you've got downvotes. Don't assume it's "random downvoting" - assume it's someone who would like to help, but can't understand your question because you haven't presented enough information, or haven't presented it clearly.

Comment: I know the format. I'm in control od datepicker but I am trying to find solution which fits "my poland custom format" and other languages which still use ISO standards. Customer wanted to use non ISO standard but it seems .NET wants ISO standard date formats.

Answer (score 1):

> I had to change poland dateformat in datepicker UI to d.m.yyyy 
>   ...
>   Example: item.arrival is string which can be in more than 10 formats. Convert.ToDateTime works for them all. BUT: item.arrival dateformat for poland language is not anymore yyyy-mm-dd (because I had requirement to change it)

Based upon what you say, your date time conversion works for all but Polish, and you (in your code) know when it is Polish.  So, handle Polish special using the format you have been required to use, and handle the other nine normally.

Comment: This solution does not scale. I had to do special case whanever I do converting which is exremely error prone. If someone forgets to do it poland page will not work :). I'm trying to find more general solution like overring datetimeformat for poland culture.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. I put it inside some PageBase class so it should more general and less error prone solution than some "if-poland-date" statements around the project.

```
CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        if (newCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "pl")
        {

            DateTimeFormatInfo myDTFI = new CultureInfo("hr-HR", false).DateTimeFormat;
            newCulture.DateTimeFormat = myDTFI;
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
            DateTimeFormatInfo dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
            ci.DateTimeFormat = myDTFI;
            CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder obj = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("pl-PL", CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement);
            obj.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(ci);
            CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister("pl-PL");
            obj.Register();

        }
```